# Access Form - relationship

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access Database where I made a form.

These are the main settings:
tables:
"**Players**" containing several fields including "name" "nationality 1" and "nationality 2"

"**Countries**" containing fields "Country" and "flag"

In my form I display the attachment field "flag" coming out of the table "country".

This field "country" in table "countries" is linked with the field "nationality 1" in my table "players".

Every "player" can hold 2 nationalities: field "nationality 1" and "nationality 2" in my form.

I want to display the flag in my form for both fields "nationality 1" and "nationality 2".

When I try to add another relationship from the field "country" in table "countries" with the field "nationality 2" in my table "players", I have a problem.
When opening my form in "Form view", I only see the background of the form. 
Al fields dissapear. In designview they still are there.
And I don't manage to make the second nationality field visible in my form.

Already searching 3 days on this issue and I can't get it fixed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please describe the error your are getting. Normally you should be able to add a foreign key without any issue. Also add the structure of you tables to the question, it will help everyone understand your problem. In other words, the script you are using to create the tables.

Comment: I don't get an error. The form fields just dissapear.

Comment: The structure of the table, what you mean with that? I am new in this Access Database.